# Converting xml to grid format

Tags: java, javascript, xml

I have got data from RSAQ_REMOTE_QUERY_CALL in xml data. I need to format that data in grid view. In that  tag gives column value and  tag gives Feild description respectively Below i have mentioned my xml data.

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
TABLES>

FPAIRS>

item>

  INDEX_A>0007</INDEX_A> 

  INDEX_U>0008 /INDEX_U> 

  TYPE>E/TYPE> 

  /item>

  /FPAIRS>

LDATA>

item>

  LINE>002:OR,004:0001,002:01,007:SCEM_02,000:, 002:PC;/</LINE> 

  /item>

  /LDATA>

LISTDESC>

item>

  FADD /> 

  FDESC>Sales Organization</FDESC> 

  FNAME>VBAK-VKORG</FNAME> 

  FCOL>SOrg.</FCOL> 

  FNAMENEW>VBAK-VKORG</FNAMENEW> 

  FNAMEINT>VKORG</FNAMEINT> 

  FKEY /> 

  FGTYP /> 

  FNZERO /> 

  FSUM /> 

  FSONLY /> 

  FSORT>00</FSORT> 

FSODS /> 
FSUBT /> 

  FLPOS>0002</FLPOS> 

  FNUMB>98</FNUMB> 

  FNUMBT /> 

  FNOSUM /> 

  FSONP /> 

  /item>

item> 
  FADD /> 

  FDESC>Distribution Channel</FDESC> 

  FNAME>VBAK-VTWEG</FNAME> 

  FCOL>DChl</FCOL> 

  FNAMENEW>VBAK-VTWEG</FNAMENEW> 

  FNAMEINT>VTWEG</FNAMEINT> 

  FKEY /> 

  FGTYP /> 

  FNZERO /> 

  FSUM /> 

  FSONLY /> 

  FSORT>00</FSORT> 

  FSODS /> 

  FSUBT /> 

  FLPOS>0003</FLPOS> 

  FNUMB>98</FNUMB> 

  FNUMBT /> 

  FNOSUM /> 

  FSONP /> 

  /item>

item>


  FADD /> 

  FDESC>Division</FDESC> 

  FNAME>VBAK-SPART</FNAME> 

  FCOL>Dv</FCOL> 

  FNAMENEW>VBAK-SPART</FNAMENEW> 

  FNAMEINT>SPART</FNAMEINT> 

  FKEY /> 

  FGTYP /> 

  FNZERO /> 

  FSUM /> 

  FSONLY /> 
  FSORT>00</FSORT> 

  FSODS /> 

  FSUBT /> 

  FLPOS>0004</FLPOS> 

  FNUMB>98/FNUMB> 

  FNUMBT /> 

FNOSUM /> 

FSONP /> 

  /item>

item>


  FADD /> 

 FDESC>Sold-to party/FDESC> 

  FNAME>VBAK-KUNNR/FNAME> 

  FCOL>Sold-to pt/FCOL> 

  FNAMENEW>VBAK-KUNNR/FNAMENEW> 

  FNAMEINT>KUNNR/FNAMEINT> 

  FKEY /> 

  FGTYP /> 

  FNZERO /> 

  FSUM /> 

  FSONLY /> 

  FSORT>00</FSORT> 

  FSODS /> 

  FSUBT /> 

  FLPOS>0005</FLPOS> 

  FNUMB>98</FNUMB> 

  FNUMBT /> 

  FNOSUM /> 

  FSONP /> 

  /item>

item> 
  FADD /> 

  FDESC>Material Number Used by Customer/FDESC> 

  FNAME>VBAP-KDMAT/FNAME> 

  FCOL>Customer Material Number/FCOL> 

  FNAMENEW>VBAP-KDMAT/FNAMENEW> 

  FNAMEINT>KDMAT/FNAMEINT> 

  FKEY /> 

  FGTYP /> 

 FNZERO /> 

  FSUM /> 

 FSONLY /> 

  FSORT>00</FSORT> 

  FSODS /> 

  FSUBT /> 

  FLPOS>0006</FLPOS> 

  FNUMB>98</FNUMB> 

  FNUMBT /> 

  FNOSUM /> 

  FSONP /> 

  /item>

item>

  FADD /> 

  FDESC>Net Weight of the Item/FDESC> 

 FNAME>VBAP-NTGEW/FNAME> 

  FCOL>Net weight/FCOL> 

  FNAMENEW>VBAP-NTGEW/FNAMENEW> 

  FNAMEINT>NTGEW/FNAMEINT> 

  FKEY /> 

  FGTYP /> 

  FNZERO /> 

  FSUM /> 

 FSONLY /> 

  FSORT>00</FSORT> 

  FSODS /> 

  FSUBT /> 

  FLPOS>0007</FLPOS> 

  FNUMB>98</FNUMB> 

  FNUMBT /> 

  FNOSUM /> 

  FSONP /> 

  /item>

  /LISTDESC>

  SELECTION_TABLE /> 

  /TABLES>
```

I need get output as like below format.

Output:

Sales Organization
 Distribution Channel
 Division
 Sold-to party
 Material Number Used by Customer
 Net Weight of the Item

OR
 0001
 01
 SCEM_02
 null
 PC

Please suggest me how to get this grid format from my xml data. Please reply as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance:)

Regards,

Joy

Comment: Format the question properly!

Comment: Java or JavaScript ? anything else we can do for you while we are here ?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention any language so i can't give you a concrete example, but basically every modern language has an XML parser, so just use the parser to get data from the xml and then you can put that data in wahtever format you like, including Grid format.

**Update:**

You need several things here:

1. If the xml's have a unified format (they all have the same
   structure) you can get an XSD or write one ([XSD Tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/default.asp)) and then
   you can use a framework like [XmlBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/) to generate java objects from
   the schema and work with them. That would be the easiest way.
2. The other option is to use the [java DOM API](http://java.sun.com/webservices/reference/tutorials/jaxp/html/dom.html). The API is a bit ugly
   but once you get used to it it's not that hard. Problem is that you
   need to take care of every xml structure manually.

   what ever method you choose, once you parsed the XML you can access the data and do whatever you like with it.

Comment: I need to do in JAVA language. Please mention some example for my task

Answer (score 0):

Search for XML parser's, and you should be able to do the rest.
DOM should be able to do the trick for the above format