# Grid View from XML data

Tags: java, xml, jsp

I have data in xml format as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <Row>
        <Sales_Doc>OR</Sales_Doc>
        <Sales_Org>0001</Sales_Org>
        <Dist_Ch>01</Dist_Ch>
        <Division>01</Division>
        <Sold_to_Party>SCEM_02</Sold_to_Party>
        <MatNo/>
        <Net_Weight>PC</Net_Weight>
        <Net_Weight_Item>590000</Net_Weight_Item>
        <Weight_Unit>KG/Weight_Unit>    
        <Sales_Unit>PC</Sales_Unit>
    </Row>
</xml>
```

I need to convert this into table or grid format using jsp or java language.
Please share ur ideas

Regards

Joy

Comment: Duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187402/converting-xml-to-grid-format/11187846#11187846

Answer (score 0):

you can parse xml file as follow:

```
<%
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse("http://localhost:8080/practice/test.xml");

NodeList nl= doc.getElementsByTagName("Sales_Doc");
NodeList n2= doc.getElementsByTagName("Sales_Org");
NodeList n3= doc.getElementsByTagName("Dist_Ch");
NodeList n4= doc.getElementsByTagName("Division");
NodeList n5= doc.getElementsByTagName("Sold_to_Party");
 // here more nodes in your xml file ....
%>
```

and display in jsp page as follow :

```
<table>
<tr>
 <%
 for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
 {
 %>
 <td><%= nl.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue() %></td>
 <td><%= n2.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue() %></td>
 <td><%= n3.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue() %></td>
 <td><%= n4.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue() %></td>
 // here more tds depending on your xml file ...
 </tr>
 <%
 }
 %>
 </table>
```

refer http://wowjava.wordpress.com/2010/04/02/displaying-xml-data-in-jsp-page/

Another way is to use xslt :

[xslt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) : XSLT (Extensible Stylesheet Language Transformations) is a declarative, XML-based language used for the transformation of XML documents. The original document is not changed; rather, a new document is created based on the content of an existing one.[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) The new document may be serialized (output) by the processor in standard XML syntax or in another format, such as HTML or plain text.[3](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_to_html.asp) XSLT is most often used to convert data between different XML schemas or to convert XML data into web pages or PDF documents.

[here is an example](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_to_html.asp)